# Few Stack related questions in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackExample {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Stack<String> sk = new Stack<String>();

        sk.push("Hello");
        sk.push("Hello1");
        sk.push("Hello2");
        sk.push("Hello3");

        System.out.println("The Values of Stack" +sk);

        Iterator it=sk.iterator();

        System.out.println("Size before pop() :"+sk.size());

        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            String iValue=(String)it.next();
            System.out.println("Iterator value :"+iValue);
        }

        String value =(String)sk.pop();

        System.out.println("value :"+value);

        System.out.println("Size After pop() :"+sk.size());



    }

}
```

Can anyone explain me the below questions.

```
while(it.hasNext()){
            String iValue=(String)it.next();
            System.out.println("Iterator value :"+iValue);
}
```

1. Why do we iterate in this manner and what does the hasNext and next
   do? Can i not do the same with an for loop.

   ```
   String value =(String)sk.pop();
   ```
2. What does the (String)sk.pop means... why does it not compile when i
   remove the (String)
3. Can anyone lead me to some good and complex Stack examples in Java

Comment: 3. I have never seen Stack used except for homework style questions in 12 years of Java development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***1. Why do we iterate in this manner and what does the `hasNext` and `next` do? Can i not do the same with an for loop.***

The [`next`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29) *fetches* the next value from the iterator, and [`hasNext`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext%28%29) tells you whether or not there *is* a next value available.

Yes, you could do the same with a for loop:

```
for (String str: sk)
    System.out.println(str);
```

should do just as fine for instance.

> ***2. What does the `(String)sk.pop` means... why does it not compile when i remove the (String)***

When you pop an element of a stack, you remove the "top" (last inserted) element. The `(String)` part is a *cast*. This is neccesary if the `pop` returns an `Object` and (you know it's actually a `String`) and you want to store it in a `String` reference.

> ***3. Can anyone lead me to some good and complex Stack examples in Java***

Complex stack examples? Uhm, no, I can't. A stack basically provide push and pop which are really simple. Whatever the example would be, it would be complex due to something else than the use of a stack, which won't help you understand stacks any better :-)

Answer (score 3):

Ad 1.: This is a standard Java [`Iterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). And since [`Stack`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) implementans [`Iterable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) you can simply write:

```
for (String item : sk)
{
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Ad 2.: Casting to `String` is required because `Iterator` is declared without generic type (which is a bad practice). Try with:

```
Iterator<String> it=sk.iterator();
```

Casting is no longer needed.

Ad 3.: Here is a simple example written in 10 minutes:

```
public static void validateXml(String xml) {
    Stack<String> tags = new Stack<String>();
    for (String tag : xml.split("\\s"))
        if(tag.startsWith("</")) {
            if (tags.isEmpty())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No start tag matching: " + tag);
            final String startTag = tags.pop();
            if (!startTag.substring(1).equals(tag.substring(2)))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start tag: " + startTag + " does not match end tag: " + tag);
        } else
            tags.push(tag);
    if (!tags.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No end tag matching: " + tags);
}
```

Usage:

```
validateXml("<a> <b> </b> <c> <d> </d> <e> </e> </c> </a>");
validateXml("<a> <b> </b> <c> <d> <e> </d> </e> </c> </a>");    //fails to validate
```

Answer (score 2):

Stack is a "legacy" collection, it extends from Vector. Both are there from the old times of Java 1.0.
It is not a good idea to use because Vector methods are synchronized.
Instead you can use the newest Deque interface, for instance, ArrayDeque or LinkedList.